# Хочу написать программу которая будет считывать информацию с ftp

Tags: ftp, android, книги

Посоветуйте статьи

Из статей я нашла только как подключатся с помощью уже имеющихся программ.

Comment: Для того, чтобы реализовать FTP в своей программе, Вам необходимо, как это ни странно, реализовать протокол FTP. Спецификации и документацию по нему можно найти в Интернете. Ну, а можно и воспользоваться готовыми библиотеками. http://bit.ly/1bxNFd9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Библиотека [Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/) содержит в себе вполне удобный `FTPClient`. А [тут](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/examples/ftp/FTPClientExample.java) вы найдёте пример использования библиотеки.